# JS function not working in ionic app

Tags: jquery, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

Hello guys I'm new to ionic. I have made a android build and ran it on my mobile device but the problem that I'm facing is that my tabs are not changing on my app which I click on them. I have a js event which removes the class and then displays a tab like this:

```
$scope.nonCompletedAction = function(event) {
  // alert('abc');
  $('#' + $('div#actions_tab a.active').attr('data-id')).css('display', 'none');
  $('div#actions_tab a.active').removeClass('active');

  $('div#actions_tab a[data-id=' + event + ']').addClass('active');
  $('#' + event).css('display', 'block');
}
```

and Here is the page which haven the tabs:

**Tab Page**

```
<ion-view view-title="Actions">
  <ion-content>
    <div id="key">
      <ion-checkbox>
        <h2 class="ng-binding">Key Test Action</h2>
        <span class="distance ng-binding"></span>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Created : May 12, 2016</h3>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Target : May 12, 2016</h3>
      </ion-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div id="important" style="display:none">
      <ion-checkbox>
        <h2 class="ng-binding">Important Test Action</h2>
        <span class="distance ng-binding"></span>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Created : May 12, 2016</h3>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Target : May 12, 2016</h3>
      </ion-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div id="additional" style="display:none">
      <ion-checkbox>
        <h2 class="ng-binding">Additional Test Action</h2>
        <span class="distance ng-binding"></span>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Created : May 12, 2016</h3>
        <h3 class="ng-binding">Target : May 12, 2016</h3>
      </ion-checkbox>
    </div>

    <ion-footer-bar>
      <div class="tabs-striped  tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
        <div class="tabs" id="actions_tab">
          <a class="tab-item active" data-id="key" ng-click="nonCompletedAction('key')">
            <i class="icon ion-home"></i> Key
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item " data-id="important" ng-click="nonCompletedAction('important')">
            <i class="icon ion-star"></i> Important
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item " data-id="additional" ng-click="nonCompletedAction('additional')">
            <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i> Additional
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

That was working when I viewed it using chrome browser but in the app it is not working. Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong.

and I would like to one more thing that does ionic render html views or does it convert our code to native libraries and is there any way to debug the app

Answer (score 1):

Ionic renders views as HTML, in fact you could think of it as an embedded web browser inside your ionic app, and native device functionalities (like camera) are available to you via cordova javascript plugins.

In order to debug your ionic app on an android device, connect your android device to your machine and make sure usb debugging is enabled, and then navigate to "chrome://inspect" from your chrome browser while the app is running, you should be able to debug it as normal html page.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: I have enabled remote debugging and went to `chrome://inspect` but it is showing me this message `No devices detected. Please read the remote debugging documentation to verify your device is enabled for USB debugging.` My mobile device is lg g3

Comment: make sure your app is running on your android device.